# Proper source of xncore for compiling svn opencv with openni support?

Tags: ros, opencv, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just upgraded my opencv svn to 2.2.9 and am building it with OpenNI support on a Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit system, already having installed the apt-get available openni-dev (either because I have ros installed or it's part of ubuntu repositories now).

I used `-D WITH_OPENNI=ON` and `-D OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openni/` with cmake, and this generated this error:

```
"WARNING, PrimeSensor Module binaries directory (set by OPENNI_PRIME_SENSOR_MODULE_BIN_DIR variable) is not found or does not have 
PrimeSensor Module binaries."
```

In the OpenCVFindOpenNI.cmake I found this was due to XnCore not being found- this happened to be on my system in a ros installed directory `/.../ros/ni/ni/ps_engine/lib/libXnCore.so`, but where should I get it from if I don't want to install ros if I'm to install opencv on another system?

The above compiles opencv fine, but kinect_maps fails

```
Kinect opening ...
done.
Can not open a capture object.
```

Which might be the source of a separate question, unless I shouldn't be using the openni-dev package at all and it's causing that problem also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10136/proper-source-of-xncore-for-compiling-svn-opencv-with-openni-support?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install OpenNI and PrimeSense sensor module from source. That's what I did.

1. Get the source codes

   $ git clone https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.git

   $ git clone https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor.git
2. Compile them in order (follow their README instructions of each package to satisfy requirements/dependencies)
3. Re-build (Cmake) your openCV.

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1